# Custom loss function- Keras-

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to implement a mixed model where part of it is a variational autoencoder and the other part takes the latent space and makes predictions on the properties of the input. I'd like to train these two models jointly. Here are my models:

```
# build encoder model
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape, name='encoder_input')
x = Dense(intermediate_dim1, activation='relu')(inputs)
x1 = Dense(intermediate_dim2, activation='relu')(x)
x2 = Dense(intermediate_dim3, activation='relu')(x1)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(x2)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(x2)

# use reparameterization trick to push the sampling out as input
# note that "output_shape" isn't necessary with the TensorFlow backend
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])

# instantiate encoder model
encoder = Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
```

```
# build decoder model
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling1')
x1 = Dense(intermediate_dim3, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
x2 = Dense(intermediate_dim2, activation='relu')(x1)
x3 = Dense(intermediate_dim1, activation='relu')(x2)
outputs = Dense(2*original_dim+1, activation='sigmoid')(x3)

# instantiate decoder model
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
```

```
#build property predictor model
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling2')
x1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
x2 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x1)
outputs = Dense(property_dim, activation='sigmoid')(x2)

predModel = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='predictor')
```

This is the full model that has the inupts of the encoder and the output of only the predictor model.

```
#build full model
vaeOutputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
predOutputs = predModel(encoder(inputs)[0])
vaePred = Model(inputs, [vaeOutputs,predOutputs], name='vae_fullimage')
vaePred.summary()
```

Now I have trouble defining the loss function and training the model:

This is my attempt:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    help_ = "Load h5 model trained weights"
    parser.add_argument("-w", "--weights", help=help_)
    help_ = "Use mse loss instead of binary cross entropy (default)"
    parser.add_argument("-m",
                        "--mse",
                        help=help_, action='store_true')
    #args = parser.parse_args()
    args = parser.parse_known_args()[0]
    models = (encoder, decoder)
    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
            kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
            kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
            kl_loss *= -0.5

            reconstruction_loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true[0], y_pred[0])
            reconstruction_loss*= original_dim

            #y_pred = predOutputs

            prediction_loss =K.square(y_pred[1] - y_true[1])

            total_loss =  K.mean(prediction_loss, axis= -1) + K.mean (reconstruction_loss) + K.mean(kl_loss)
            return total_loss

    optimizer =  keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    vaePred.compile(optimizer, custom_loss)
    vaePred.summary()

    if args.weights:
        vaePred.load_weights(args.weights)
    else:
        # train the autoencoder
        history =vaePred.fit(x=x_train, y=[x_train,property_train],
                epochs=epochs,
                callbacks=callbacks,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                validation_data=(x_test, [x_test,property_test]))
```

Comment: I defined a custom_loss(y_true,y_pred) and also only used the predOutputs as the output of the whole model.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are training an autoencoder(AE) (a *generative* model that seeks to predict itself).  The outputs for an AE should equal the inputs if it is perfect.  Therefore you should change *y_true* to be *inputs*.

change:

```
prediction_loss = mse(y_true, predOutputs)
```

to be:

```
prediction_loss = mse(inputs, predOutputs)
```

note: I have not run or tested any of this code. It appears to be example code from Keras.

Comment: Part of the model is a variational autoencoder (VAE) that has to reconstruct the input and the other part is trying to use the latent space of the VAE to predict some properties.

Comment: I updated the code. It runs with no error now but it has a jumpy loss

Comment: yes, of course...part of the code is an AE.  Well, glad it now runs for you...isn't that your question? It is customary to have one question for a SO posting...and you have now edited the original question that I tried answering.  You should just close/delete the question and ask your next *specific* question. Jumpy loss is a matter of tuning/architecture...the first step of which is either running it longer or reducing the learning rate...nobody is going to do that for you.

Comment: Okay, thank you. yes, I understand. I thought maybe someone can detect something wrong with the code. It gives very odd results. But, I think I should research more. Thank you